# USB device does not appear in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, usb-drive

I got a problem . when I'm connecting my USB drive my drive does not apear in desktop I have run the command -

```
 dmesg | tail
```

and the output is -

```
[ 1178.937179] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: N85H8K1R  
[ 1178.938060] scsi10 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0  
[ 1179.937197] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 8GB    8.07 PQ: 0      
ANSI: 4
[ 1179.939902] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0  
[ 1179.940616] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.02 GB/7.47GiB)  
[ 1179.941377] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off  
[ 1179.941382] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00  
[ 1179.942066] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't
 support DPO or FUA  
[ 1179.950956]  sdc: unknown partition table  
[ 1179.953080] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

what should I do now ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is something wrong with the partition partition table on the USB. *[ 1179.950956]  sdc: unknown partition table*

Have a look at the answer here, [Running Ubuntu from a USB Flash drive on Acer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190996/running-ubuntu-from-a-usb-flash-drive-on-acer/222064#222064) .

If your device contains no valuable data, write a new partition table using e.g. gparted.
If it contains valuable data, you should make a raw backup before trying to restore the partition table.

To make raw backup you can use e.g. dd. `sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=usb-image.iso`
Remember to substitute X.